# How to write a shell script to disable the database accounts from a list of user IDs

Tags: scripting, users

I am new to Unix scripting...I have a list of userids for terminated employees. I want to write a script that will check these userids against my databases and disable/remove the user accounts associated to those userids. Doing this manually for each database and for each server will take an inordinate amount of time. I'll appreciate any help I can get as well as the constructive criticism.

Edit:

This is for Oracle RDBMS. Thanks for pointing that out @sticky bit
Thanks @Verace

Comment: Why disable them? Why not remove them completely?

Comment: "constructive criticism": Start by telling the DBMS you target at.

Comment: @sticky bit: You are right, I should have mentioned that this is for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

For `mysql` you can run something like that from any shell:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword < /path/some_script.sql
```

Modern, more secure and more sophisticated way is to use the login-path:

```
mysql --login-path=root_on_server < /path/some_script.sql
```

where `some_script.sql` is a plain text file containing SQL statements separated by `;`. Here you can GRANT/REVOKE/DROP privileges as you want.

Almost every other DBMS have the very similar CLI functionality so you can use that approach somehow.

Comment: Thanks Kondybas. I should have mentioned that this is for an Oracle RDBMS